# How to get Mail.app to display duplicate messages on Big Sur

Tags: mail.app

I am using Big Sur and found that the mail app hides the duplicates of the messages.
Recently I used the following comment but doesn't work on Big Sur

```
defaults write com.apple.mail _AlwaysShowDuplicates -bool true
```